# How to catch an arity exception in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, exception

I am trying to catch an arity exception like so:

```
(try
  (inc)
  (catch clojure.lang.ArityException e
    (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e))))))
```

In this case, I am invoking `inc` without a passing it a number, and it rightly throws an exception. However, that exception does not get caught when I run it:

```
(try
  (inc)
  (catch clojure.lang.ArityException e
    (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e))))))

; => CompilerException clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core/inc--inliner--4489
```

Attempting to catch any `Exception` generally instead of `clojure.lang.ArityException` still throws it.

I am sure anyone seasoned in Clojure development will catch my mistake immediately.

Comment: If you call (apply inc []), I believe it will get caught. But what is the utility of catching this arity exception? Or is it just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can catch `ArityException`s in some cases; depending on the context and the function causing the `ArityException`.

---

I'm going to admit right off the bat that I'm speculating on some aspects because I've never explored this in too much depth before.

First, look what happens if you call `inc` in a context where it's obvious that the number of supplied arguments is wrong:

```
(inc)
CompilerException clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core/inc--inliner--4489, compiling: . . .
```

The interesting part is `inc--inliner--4489`. If you look at the definition for `inc`, it has this meta-data attached to it:

```
:inline (fn [x] `(. clojure.lang.Numbers (~(if *unchecked-math* 'unchecked_inc 'inc) ~x)))
```

I've never looked into `:inline` in too much depth before, but I've always been under the assumption it means that it will attempt to inline the call to (marginally) reduce overhead. In this case, it's attempting to inline `inc` to just be a call to either `clojure.lang.Numbers/inc`, or `clojure.lang.Numbers/unchecked_inc`; depending on the state of `*unchecked-math*`. Also note how the error starts:

```
CompilerException clojure.lang.ArityException
```

In your example, you can't catch straight `(inc)` because that call fails at *compile time* before the code is even run. It knows that `(inc)` will never be correct, so it fails immediately. This is a good thing though. `(inc)` *will* never be correct, so there's no point in trying to catch it anyways.

---

There are circumstances however where catching an arity exception *may* make sense (although there's likely better ways of approaching the problem`*`). Say you disallow the call to `inc` to be inlined by, as @Rulle suggested, `apply`ing the arguments:

```
(try
  (apply inc [])

  (catch clojure.lang.ArityException e
    (println "Caught!")))

Caught!
```

The compiler can't know for sure whether or not `inc` will fail because it depends on the number of arguments supplied to `apply`; which may depend on things at runtime. In this case, the code is actually capable of being run, and is also capable of having its `ArityException` caught.

---

Taking `:inline` out of the equation, you can also see that a custom function of yours can have its `ArityException` caught with less fuss, since the call isn't inlined, so it doesn't fail at compile time:

```
(defn hello [arg]) 

(try
  (hello) ; No apply

  (catch clojure.lang.ArityException e
    (println "Caught!")))

Caught!
```

---

`*` I can't say I've ever had to catch an `ArityException`, and I can't think of any circumstances where doing so would be appropriate. Even if you're using `apply`, it would make more sense to verify the arguments ahead of time, or even rethink your use of `apply`. If using `apply` leads to an `ArityException`, you probably have a flaw in your logic somewhere that use of `try` is just putting a band-aid over.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. How would you verify the arguments ahead of time? Through something like `(:arglists (meta #'some-fn))`?

Comment: @weltschmerz You generally shouldn't need to handle Arity Exceptions at Runtime; I was just showing that you could. Overwhelmingly, Arity Exceptions represent a flaw in your program. The only time you should need to handle them is if you're doing something like designing an API and want to handle "untrusted" callbacks failing gracefully. In other cases, let your program fail, debug it, and try to fix it.

Comment: Got it. Btw, I'm doing this because I'm trying to build a function that iteratively invokes another function to try and replicate its implementation. It's not given any information as to the target function's arity, so I figured I would let it try out different numbers of args until it stops throwing exceptions... So I *think* it would need to happen at runtime....

Comment: @weltschmerz I'm interested. How would you try and replicate another function's implementation? I would think that there would be infinite implementation possibilities (or at least effectively infinite possibilities) to try. But yes, testing for a function's arity would be a corner case; as odd as it may be. And yes, that would need to happen at runtime, unless you hardcoded all possible arity tries so they can be checked at compile time. You could actually probably use a macro to generate the test calls at compile time to ease this.

Comment: I think it would need to happen through trial and error, so a genetic algorithm. Not sure yet.

Comment: @weltschmerz Let me know when you decide. I've written a decent genetic algorithm library (that's on my Github). It was just a practice project, but it ended up really well. Unless you want to reinvent the wheel, it might be a nice starting point.

Comment: @weltschmerz Ya. It's extraordinarily poorly documented unfortunately. I can create a quick start guide to show basic usage. I probably should anyways in case I want to use it later.